# How to write a finder that implements Like command in Liferay Service Builder?

Tags: liferay

How is it possible to write a finder in Service Builder that implements the LIKE command of SQL?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about how to use [`LIKE` of `SQL`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) with Liferay's `DynamicQuery`.

You can use the [`ilike`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/orm/RestrictionsFactoryUtil.html#ilike%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method of the [`RestrictionsFactoryUtil`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/orm/RestrictionsFactoryUtil.html) as:

```
DynamicQuery dyQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(MyCustomClass.class);

dyQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.ilike("propertyName", "anyValue"))
              .addOrder(OrderFactoryUtil.asc("propertyName")
           );
```

This method `ilike` of liferay works similar to [Hibernate Restriction's](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-narrowing) [`ilike`](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#ilike%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method.

Hope this helps. If you have some other thing in mind kindly elaborate your question to give the specifics and some scenario or code which you have tried will also help.

Comment: this does not really differ from my answer or am i missing something?

Comment: @MatthiasG I specified the use of the method `ilike` which is a direct equivalent of the `LIKE` command. So my answer becomes a little more specific to the question asked. Also using `DynamicQuery` does not necessarily involve writing a `*FinderImpl`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your finderImpl you can create a com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.Criterion,
using this Criterion you can create Queries like
`Criterion criterion = RestrictionsFactoryUtil.gt("PropertyName", value);`
Create DynamicQuery than by using
`DynamicQuery query = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(YourModel.class).add(criterion);`
and excecute it
`List results = YourLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(query);`

RestrictionsFactoryUtil has many evaluations, i think you will find what you are looking for

HTH